# MFC List Control scrolling shows extra grid lines

Tags: mfc

I use the MFC list control in report view with grid lines to display data in a vaguely spreadsheet manner.

Sometimes when the user scrolls vertically through the control, extra grid lines are drawn, which looks terrible.

This does not happen when the slider or the mousewheel are used to scroll, only when the little down arrow button at the  bottom of the scroll control is used.

It seems that this occurs when the size of the list control window is not an exact even number of rows, so that a partial row is visible at the bottom.

If I adjust the size of the list control so that there is no partial rows visible, the problem is solved.  However, it will appear when the program is run on another computer, presumably because the number of pixels occupied by a row changes.

I am assuming that it is an interaction between screen resolution, font size and "dialog units".

I guess that I need to programmatically force the size of the control when it is created.  But what size?

I have tried using the ApproximateViewRect() method but I cannot get it to work.  Perhaps this method does not know about report view?

The other method, I suppose, would be to create my own specialization of CListCtrl and over-ride whatever method is doing the scrolling.  This seems likely to be a lot of work.

This screenshot shows a closely related problem where the grid lines go missing

[image]

and here is one with the extra grid lines

[image]

The only difference between these two and between them and one which scrolls perfectly is a few pixels different in the vertical size of the control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this bug in the MFC List Control you need to specialize the control, over-ride the method wich responds to the scroll, and force it to redraw the list completely after it has done the scroll.

interface header

```
class cSmoothListControl : public CListCtrl
{
public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
};
```

implementation:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(cSmoothListControl, CListCtrl)
ON_WM_VSCROLL()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void cSmoothListControl::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    // call base class method to do scroll
    CListCtrl::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);

    // force redraw to cover any mess that may be created
    Invalidate();
    UpdateWindow();
}
```

Comment: This answer just adds peripheral message map cruft to my already sufficient answer.

Comment: Ajryan, I did not find your answer sufficient.  When I implemented it, it failed.  It took about an hour to find the necessary code you had left out.  I thought to save others this grief.

Comment: Completely ridiculous.  That's like asking how to add two numbers and saying the answer was not sufficient because it didn't say how to print the result.

Comment: sorry, I agree with ravenspoint on this. OnVScroll never gets called if ON_WM_VSCROLL() is not declared in the messagemap, and it is not mentioned in the msdn documentation at all. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhfk142k%28VS.80%29.aspx 
you can find this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfk31946%28VS.80%29.aspx only if you already know that a message map entry is expected.

Comment: Well I also think it's ridiculous. Any MFC programmer worth his salt should know to add a bloody messagemap entry to get the overridden function to be called. Also -1 for crappy tagging.

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a bug related to "smooth scrolling," here's a workaround:

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    __super::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
    Invalidate();
    UpdateWindow();
}
```

Comment: To make the framework call the overide, it is necessary to add it to the message map.

Comment: Details of message map coding in my answer

Comment: Message map is something everyone working in MFC should understand, not specifically pertinent to this answer.

Comment: You're not going to accept this answer since he didn't put the message map entry?? Geesh! The message map thing could have just been appended here as a comment (or edit you question with it).

Answer (score 1):

I recall this being a bug in the ListView (not just through MFC, but the common control in general) itself. A quick google on this seems to hit a lot of people coming to that same conclusion. I guess since Windows Explorer doesn't have gridlines they don't feel the need fix this? I remember this back in the late 90's.

I guess the trick would be to invalidate the window after a scroll - maybe in response to a VSCROLL message? Just a guess.

Comment: What search terms did you use in google?  I could find nothing.  Is "ListView" the same as "List Control", which is what I am using>

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening with the stock listview, or is it custom draw? I've never seen redrawing issues with the standard windows controls.

Maybe you can post a screenshot to illustrate the problem? I presume you'd prefer to fix the redraw issue and not size the control exactly?

Comment: Completely stock.

The problem is hard to reproduce, and I am not clear on how to post a picture here.

Comment: Ok I see. Is this control created with the resource editor, or do you create it dynamically (in OnInitDialog() with m_ListCtrl.Create(...) for example?) If you're doing the last, have you tried playing with WS_CLIPCHILDREN and WM_CLIPSIBLINGS? That has fixed similar redraw issues for me in the past.

Comment: It is created in the resource editor.  I have no problem creating it in OnInitDialog ( I do this for other things ).  I do not know anything about using WS_CLIPCHILDREN - will take a look.

Comment: myZoneList.ModifyStyle( 0, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS , 0 );  Adding this code in OnInitDialog has no effect, neither does it if use WS_CLIPCHILDREN.  My quick reading suggests it would only if the rows were windows, which I doubt.